# Getting profile pictures via graph api results in "application request limit reached"

Tags: facebook-graph-api

We receive "(#4) Application request limit reached" error when a page is showing the profile picture of a large amount of users.

Does it happens just because of referring the user's profile picture via graph api? e.g. "https://graph.facebook.com/{user-id}/picture"

If we will use the direct picture link (e.g. "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/...") and update it using the real-time updates the problem will be solved?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing too many server calls to facebook app at once, you have a fair chance to get the error. Please check if getting the direct link is permitted in the facebook terms and conditions for platforms. Or else you can store the picture when someone connects through facebook in your server, but again, facebook changed privacy policy recently, so please check with that too.

Comment: Thanks! The terms and conditions permit caching of data in order to improve user experience.

Comment: Yep, they included it very recently.